# I need to Insert the content of the text file into a database. Database created. But Table was not created

Tags: python

**Please help me. What is the problem of my code?**

File Content:

My first file is written from Python.

This data will be written to the file.

---

Don't delete existing data

Add this to the existing file

```
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="")
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute('CREATE database DB')

cursor.execute('use DB')
file_table = 'CREATE table data(id integer(2) primary key AUTOINCREMENT, content CHAR)'
cursor.execute(file_table)

query = 'INSERT INTO data VALUES (%s)'
file = open('test.txt', 'r')
values = (file.readlines())

cursor.execute(query, values)

con.commit()
con.close()
file.close()
```

Errors -
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFmtA.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code, first, and the cause of the error message you posted, is that it should be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and not `AUTOINCREMENT`.
Second you need to specify the column you insert values into, i.e. `query = 'INSERT INTO data (content) VALUES (%s)'`
Third you should insert the list using `cursor.executemany(query, values)` where each row corresponds to a tuple containing the value since `cursor.execute()` cannot insert multiple rows at once.
Fourth `readlines()` returns the newline character at the end of each line, which you probably do not want, so to read the file and insert them you could e.g. do ~:

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO data (content) VALUES (%s)'
with open('test.txt', 'rt') as file:
    values = [(value,) for value in file.read().splitlines()]
cursor.executemany(query, values)
```

Comment: Thank You so much @erikced .I solved my problem.

Comment: That’s great @SahiruLakshan, could you please mark the answer as accepted if it helped?

Comment: Ok done .@erikced

Answer (score 1):

The error you show means that you want to insert your data in the table `file` which doesn't exist. You've created a table `data`. When you initialize `query`, do `query = 'INSERT INTO data VALUES (%s)'` instead.